# Pushbutton Circuit - Triggers Event when no button press

Tags: raspberry-pi, interrupts, button, gpio-external-interrupt

I have been using the circuit below. I have noticed there are times the circuit will trigger on its own without any button press. Sometimes it can trigger a few times within an hour. The components are soldered onto a PCB Board. I have my raspberry pi GPIO set as a pull down (GPIO.PUD_DOWN). The interrupt event is triggered on GPIO.RISING and I have a SW bouncetime of 50 seconds. The 3.3V source is connected to the 3.3V and GND rails on the Raspberry Pi. The Raspberry Pi is connected to a wall outlet using a 5V 3A adapter. The wires connecting the GPIO pin to the pushbutton are stranded copper. The distance between the GPIO pin to the pushbutton is about 3-5 inches. I have a PiCamera, 5V 0.5A Motorboard, 10mA Fan and 4 leds (<5mA total) connected to the Raspberry Pi as well in case load would be an issue. Power consumption is about 4 Watts on average.

Is my pull down resistor too low? Possibly a Raspberry Pi GPIO issue? Something else to look into or change circuit wise?

[image]

Interrupt Setup via Python:

```
GPIO.setup(button_gpio,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.add_event_detect(button_gpio,GPIO.RISING, handler_funtion, bouncetime=50000)
```

Comment: 50 seconds of bounce time? Are you breadboard ?

Comment: @KiranPhalak I just overshot the number a lot to hopefully guarantee no bouncing signal. It was not the case. So I need to pinpoint the true cause here. I am using a PCB for my circuit.

Comment: Where does the 3.3V come from?  The Pi?  If not, do you have it grounded to the Pi correctly?

Comment: Typically this circuit would have a capacitor across R1 to debounce environmental noise.  1uF, 0.1uF or 10nF.  The capacitance value depends on what rise time can be tolerated for at the GPIO input.  That would be my first try.

Comment: What does the power rails look like when the button spontaneously triggers?  Requires a 'scope and external triggers on GPIO and power.

Comment: @user30884, switches don't typically have capacitors across them. It depends on the environment but there's almost always no need. A capacitor causes a slow rise and/or fall time and that's not helping a digital input, particularly if it's not a Schmitt trigger input. Do debouncing in digitally.and remove unnecessary capacitor part and cost.

Comment: @ScottSeidman The 3.3 is from the Pi and the Ground also goes to the Pi.

Comment: don't pull down the gate.  you're doing that extrnally already.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Would pulling down the gate SW wise and HW wise cause an issue?

Comment: Your debounce time will come from your switch's datasheet but figures like 10 ms are normally plenty or 50 ms in the extreme. The problem's not in the circuit you've drawn so it must be in the implementation and that's where your question lacks detail. Please edit it to explain the connections between the two, your actual software debounce method and so on. Thanks.

Comment: @TonyM I added some more details. Is there anything specific I can add that would help clarify possible issues?

Comment: Same as before, please edit your question and explain the connections between the two boards :-) Are they three feet apart, one inch,...?

Comment: @TonyM Updated again. Let me know if I left something you might find useful out.

Comment: The internal pulldown will form a divider with your 2.2k

Comment: how long are the wires, what sort of wire is used

Comment: @ScottSeidman so i should remove the 2.2k?

Comment: @Jasen they are copper thread wires. None of which are more than 5 inches (127 mm) long.

Comment: @user30884  no, just no. doing that will burn out the button and inject noise onto the supply rails.

Comment: @Jasen what will burn out the button? Also, Bill below said put a capacitor but TonyM said a capacitor is not useful for digital inputs. Please clarify what is correct

Comment: a capacitor parallel to it. will cause the switch to burn out by causing large currents to flow as the capacitor suddenly discharges each time the switch closes.

Answer (score 5):

R1 is not needed if you use the internal pull down resistor.
But put a capcitor (~220nF) on the input side of the gpio.

Comment: what would the capacitor's function be?

Comment: deglitching: The capacitor soaks up external electromagnetic  interference.

Comment: so in series with the 2.2k R1 I should add a 220nF capacitor? With the capacitor being in-between R1 and the GPIO input? Also, where does external EMI come from? the Pushbutton? Or is it possible the RPi has power fluctuations within it that trigger that GPIO interrupt event?

Comment: As Scott allready mensioned. Is the ground connected? If you use this input as interrupt input from a switch it can end in problems. Filter at least the input digital.

Comment: The ground is used from the Raspberry Pi rail @Bill

Comment: @Bill how do I filter the signal? apologies in advance if prior items need to be repeated

Comment: For a switch i would use R * C ~ 5ms. Or in the software when I am to lazy to soldering. Read the input several times and only if the signal is for several consecutive times is the same (1 or 0) go on with it.